# Create texture from 3D Model

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a project and I placed a 3D model on my screen with a transparent background. Now my question is, is it possible to extract a texture (backbuffer) from the model itself and not the whole screen(with the background) without working with the Boundingsphere ? I should have a texture or Bitmap etc. of the model so I can place that on another texture.

Some Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render your 3D model onto a `RenderTarget`, which will yield a bitmap of the model. Keep in mind that it will have whatever lighting/shader/etc properties and/or effects applied.

You can set a `RenderTarget` as part of a call to `SpriteBatch.Begin()`*

*actual API may differ - it's a bit rusty and I don't have XNA handy on this machine